# If $a^2+a b+b^2=40$ and $a^2-\sqrt{a b}+b=5$, then find $a^2+\sqrt{a b}+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given this problem to solve with elementary methods (High School level).

> Knowing that
> $$\begin{align}
> a^2+a b+b^2 &=40 \\
> a^2-\sqrt{a b}+b &=\phantom{0}5
> \end{align}$$
> find
> $$a^2+\sqrt{a b}+b$$

I tried to look for $\sqrt{a b}$, since the requested quantity is

$$a^2+\sqrt{a b}+b=(a^2-\sqrt{a b}+b)+2\sqrt{ab}=5 + 2\sqrt{ab}$$
So I set
$$x=a^2;\;y=\sqrt{ab};\;b=z$$
and the system became
$$x+y^2+z^2=40;\;x-y-z=5$$
subtracting the two equations I got
$$z^2-z+y^2+y-35=0$$
which has one real solution when the discriminant is zero.

That is

$1-4(y^2+y-35)=0$

and then

$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(-1\pm\sqrt{142}\right)$

and finally
$$a^2+\sqrt{a b}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$$

I know that there are other solutions because I've found them with *Wolfram Mathematica*, but I couldn't find them with elementary methods.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Very interesting your question and my regards from Sicily to the colleague. +1

Comment: Are you it is not $$a-\sqrt{ab}+b=5?$$  Then we can use $$(x^2-xy+y^2)(x^2+xy+y^2)=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, it is not. They sent me the photo of the book...

Comment: @Raffaele as you proceed, $1-4(y^2+y-35)= k \ge 0 $ then you can get solutions varry over $k\in[0,\infty) $

Comment: As you can't get $1-4(y^2+y-35) \lt 0 $ , so, I think , over $k$ you will get all the possible solutions.

Comment: @Raffaele Are you only looking for real solutions?

Comment: Wolfram gives three possible values for $a$ which are roots of the polynomial $a^8-2a^7-16a^6+24a^5+33a^4+120a^3+240a^2-950a+225$. Moreover if $x=a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b$, then $(x-a^2+a)(5-a^2+a)=40$. The values of $x$ are roots of $x^{8} - 36 x^{7} + 604 x^{6} - 6620 x^{5} + 46638 x^{4} - 202780 x^{3} + 761740 x^{2} - 1350500 x - 7124375$.

Comment: You wrote "and finally $a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$. I know that there are other solutions because I've found them with Wolfram Mathematica". If you mean that Wolfram Mathematica showed that it is possible that $a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$, then what are $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2=40,a^2-\sqrt{ab}+b=5$ and $a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$ ? Also, what are "other solutions" ? I've got the same equation as the one written at the end of Fabio Lucchini's comment which implies that it is impossible that $a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$.

Comment: @mathlove: The values $a^2+\sqrt{ab}+b=4\pm\sqrt{142}$ are wrong by comparison with approximate values given by [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Bab%2Bb%5E2%3D40%2C+a%5E2-sqrt%28ab%29%2Bb%3D5%2C+a%5E2%2Bsqrt%28ab%29%2Bb%3Dx).

Comment: Even with the photo of the book in hand, given what's been shown so far I think it's clear that Occam's Razor suggests the correct answer is 'the book has a typo'. The methods being thrown at this problem are far from high-school level.

Comment: I agree with the last comment. It is very likely that there is a typo in the book. Probably the correct version of the problem should have $a-\sqrt{ab}+b$ as the second equation and should ask for the value of  $a+\sqrt{ab}+b$, which in this case would be $8$, as confirmed here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Ba+b%2Bb%5E2+%3D40%2C+a-%5Csqrt%7Ba+b%7D%2Bb%3D5%2C+a%2B%5Csqrt%7Ba+b%7D%2Bb%3Dx+++++++

Answer (score 1):

We could try to "brute force" it at the high school level. Start with the second equation
$$a^2 - \sqrt{ab} + b = 5$$
$$a^2  + b -5 = \sqrt{ab}$$
$$a^4 + b^2 + 25 + 2a^2 b -10a^2 -10b = ab$$
$$b^2 + ( 2a^2 -10 -a) b + (a^4 -10a^2 +25) =0$$
$$b = \frac{-(2a^2 -10 -a) \pm \sqrt{( 2a^2 -10 -a)^2 - 4(a^4 -10a^2 +25))}}{2}$$
$$b = \frac{-(2a^2 -10 -a) \pm \sqrt{a (-4 a^2 + a + 20)}}{2}$$
Now let's just call $b=x \pm \sqrt{y}.$
$$b^2 = x^2 \pm 2x\sqrt{y} + y$$
$$ab = ax \pm a\sqrt{y}$$
Plug this into the second equation:
$$a^2 +ab + b^2 =40$$
$$a^2 + ax \pm a\sqrt{y} + x^2 \pm 2x\sqrt{y} + y =40 $$
$$(\pm a \pm 2x)\sqrt{y}=40 -a^2 - ax - x^2 -y$$
$$(a^2 \pm 2xa + 4x^2)y=(40 -a^2 - ax - x^2 -y)^2$$
Now plug in for $x, y$ and solve for $a$. What you end up with is:
$$-225 + 950 a - 290 a^2 - (255 a^3)/2 - (53 a^4)/4 - (45 a^5)/2 + 
 14 a^6 + 2 a^7 - a^8 =0$$ This is not tractable, and it is likely the problem has a typo.

If you type in Mathematica

```
Solve[{a^2 + a*b + b^2 == 40, \[Sqrt](a*b) + 5 == a^2 + b}, {a, b}]
```

It will spit out 3 gross looking expressions possible answers. If you then evaluate these for $a^2 + b + \sqrt{ab}$

```
a^2 + b + Sqrt[a b] /. %OUTPUT NUMBER
```

Then the resulting expression doesn't simplify nicely. (Which is not a guarantee; Mathematica's simplify function is far from perfect).

Comment: I discovered (too late) that the problem, a problem printed on a BOOK, had a typo!!! Second equation was $$a^2+\sqrt{a b}+b^2$$. And the quantity to find was $$a^2-\sqrt{a b}+b^2$$. Which is almost *trivial* to solve...

Comment: Please add this comment to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to graph out these equations of lines.
Find the values of $a,b$ and plug into the desired output equation:

1. Equation of a line:
   see link [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Bab%2Bb%5E2%3D40+%3B+a%5E2+-+sqrt%28ab%29+%2B+b+%3D+5).
2. Look at the possible values and
3. plug answers into the final equation:

[image: List item]